# How to load dependencies (of SQLite3) recursively with SystemJS (in Typescript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, sqlite, typescript-typings

I recently played around with typescript, Angular2 and nw.js.

I have a little project based on the Angular2 quickstart guide for plain javascript and got it working. I added sqlite3 and got this to work even in nw.js, so I could load some heroes from the database.

Now as the Angular tutorial may indicate, typescript seems the way to go, when using Angular2. So I tried another project, followed all these steps in the tutorial and got it working as well as locally (in the browser) and in nw.js.

However I can not get sqlite3 to work in neither of them.
As I understand, the best way to add js libraries in typescript is to add typings to them. Fortunately there is a sqlite3 DefinitelyTyped lib.

I installed sqlite3 with the following command:

> npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=x64 --target=0.15.4

and installed typings with

> typings install dt~sqlite3 --global --save

Now I want to import sqlite3 on my service, so I added these lines to it:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts"/>
import * as sqlite3 from 'sqlite3';
let db = new sqlite3.Database('../data/database.sqlite');
```

The typescript now compiles without errors, however when I load the site in either the browser or nw.js it tries to download sqlite3 directly from root and give me this error:

```
Error loading http://localhost:3000/sqlite3 as "sqlite3" from http://localhost:3000/app/hero.service.js
```

sqlite3 is of course not in project root, so it runs in a 404 for this. But why is it looking for it on this place anyway?

My app structure is like at the end of the [routing step in the Angular2 tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html)

```
project
|
+-- app
|   |
|   +-- hero.service.ts
|
+-- data
|   |
|   +-- database.sqlite
|
+-- node_modules
|   |
|   +-- sqlite 3
|        |
|        +-- sqlite3.js
|
+-- typings
|   |
|   +-- index.d.ts
|   |
|   +-- globals
|       |
|       +-- sqlite3
|           |
|           +-- index.d.ts
```

My typings.json:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320",
    "sqlite3": "registry:dt/sqlite3#2.2.3+20160316155526"
  }
}
```

Top of my hero.service.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts"/>

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

import * as sqlite3 from 'sqlite3';

sqlite3.verbose();
let db = new sqlite3.Database('../data/database.sqlite');

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    // ...
```

Edit:
So thanks to @arpit-agarwal I added sqlite3 to my systemjs.config.js and now the error is another. It fails to load sqlite dependencies like node-pre-gyp, paths, events, and so on. I can set these in map property, but it can clearly not be the way to go, to set the path to every dependency (and sqlite3 has a lot of them) by hand. This doesn't work for event, being a package contained in node.js. My systemjs.config.js looks like this now:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
        'sqlite3': 'node_modules/sqlite3'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'sqlite3': { main: 'sqlite3.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade',
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Full error message after systemjs.config.js edit:

```
Error loading http://localhost:3000/node-pre-gyp as "node-pre-gyp" from http://localhost:3000/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
```

Also get 404 on

```
http://localhost:3000/path
http://localhost:3000/events
http://localhost:3000/util
```

So is there a proper way to tell systemjs to load dependency modules as well?

Edit2:
I set up a project with angular-cli-build and did the steps that @arpit-agarwal suggested but I run into the same problem that it fails to load events and path.
ng build fails with:

```
Error on fetch for node-pre-gyp at file:///C:/Dev/ang_test/tmp/bundle_plugin-input_base_path-wATtw5FK.tmp/0/node-pre-gyp
    Loading vendor/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
    Loading vendor/sqlite3/sqlite3.js
    Loading app/hero.service.js
    Loading app/heroes/heroes.component.js
    Loading app/app.routes.js
    Loading main.js
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Dev\ang_test\tmp\bundle_plugin-input_base_path-wATtw5FK.tmp\0\node-pre-gyp
```

I also tried a project with jspm but cannot get Angular2 to work unless I install it with npm instead jspm which seems pointless to me. Also this led to the same problem.
After reading several blogs and tutorials about Angular, JSPM and so on and I am running out of ideas to get this working.

What is bugging me here is, it did work with plain javascript. I have an app running in nw.js with Angular2 that is loading data from a SQLite3 database. But it's not easy to write an Angular2 app with plain javascript. Nearly all docs and tutorials use typescript. And I can see, it's a nice language. Maybe I have a look on react.

Is there an alternative, like use anything other than SystemJS? I'm still very new to node.js.

Answer (score -2):

You need to copy `sqlite3` to `vendor` directory by updating `angular-cli-build.js` file. 
`sqlite3/**/*.*`  as a entry in `vendorNpmFiles` tag. 
Once you run build via `npm start`. You should manully verify this file exists in `dist/vendor` directory. 
You also need to update `system.config.ts` to look for sqllite3 in vendor directory. Inside the `map` function add

```
Sqlite3: vendor/sqlite3 // you can give full path of JS file as well depending upon usage and error message.
```

Comment: Ok, I just looked it up, but I don't use angular-cli-build. But I added sqlite3 to map and package in system.config.js and now I got an error that node-pre-gyp is missing, which sqlite3 needs lot load internal. So it seems, that it fails now to load sqlite3 dependencies? I'm still new to node.js.

Comment: You need to copy dependencies in dist and make necessary changes in sytem.config. I don't think there is any easy way out.

Comment: So there is no other way to handle dependencies of dependencies than to set them as my own dependencies? What is with dependencies that are provided from nodejs itself?

Comment: None I am aware of. Can you check if SQLite ships with bundle which has all depnedcies merged